# При указании padding появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки

Tags: html, css

когда к `header` применяю свойство `padding` появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки, подскажите как ее убрать пожалуйста. и не спрятать свойством `overflow-x: hidden;` а исправить причину появления

```css
:root {
  --main: #12282C;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  background: var(--mainColor);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: var(--light);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: var(--light);
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 100%), url(../img/background.jpg);
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
}

.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
  background: #232122;
}

.top-nav__circle {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.header__logo {
  color: var(--main);
  font-family: 'Comic Neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <div class="top-nav__circle"></div>
  <div class="top-nav__circle"></div>
  <div class="top-nav__circle"></div>
</div>
<header>
  <div class="header__logo">
    <span>Tesmi</span>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
:root {
  --main: #12282C;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  background: var(--mainColor);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: var(--light);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: var(--light);
}

header {
  width: calc(100% - 15px) ;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600) 100%), url(../img/background.jpg);
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
}

.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
  background: #232122;
}

.top-nav__circle {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.header__logo {
  color: var(--main);
  font-family: 'Comic Neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <div class="top-nav__circle"></div>
  <div class="top-nav__circle"></div>
  <div class="top-nav__circle"></div>
</div>
  <header>
    <div class="header__logo">
      <span>Tesmi</span>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: можете объяснить пожалуйста, почему у `header` вычитается 30 px? почему именно 30 px

Comment: @Sevastopol' спасибо

Comment: @Ram Ce width 100%  занимает всю ширину браузера к к нему Вы добавляете горизонтальный padding будет вся ширина браузера + 15px от padding  появляется горизонтальный скролл (или проще я ошибся подсчете)

Comment: @Sevastopol'  исправил

Comment: @Ram Ce  удачи Вам